# Ruby on Rails - create function to list users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Users` table and a `Team` table. The foreign team key is in the user table. But I want to create a function to list the users so that I can choose the users of that team. That is, I want to call this function with some select or something of the type in the Team view. What would that function look like and what would I call it in the team view?
obs: although the foreign key of the team is in the user table, usually in the user view I would choose a team, but what I want to do is in the opposite view.

Comment: This is exactly what `has_many` and `belongs_to` is for.  Set those up and then do `team.users`.

Answer (score 2):

This is really basic stuff. Perhaps you should review the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to understand how associations work. Here's, roughly, how it goes...

If you set your `User` model up like (ignoring other attributes you probably have):

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  team_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

And you set your `Team` model up like (ignoring other attributes you probably have):

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: teams
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

And you get instantiate a `@team` variable something like:

```
@team = Team.find_by(id: 1)
```

Then you can do:

```
@team.users
```

to get all the `User`s associated with the `Team`.

BTW, this will require that a `User` has a `Team` to be saved. If you try to save a `User` without a `Team`, it won't work. If you want to save a `User` without a `Team`, then you'll have to do:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  team_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
end
```

Personally, I would prefer to do `@team.members` (because that seems more natural than `@team.users`, IMO). So, I would do something more like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: teams
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Then you can do:

```
@team.members
```

and, again, get all the `User`s associated with the `Team`.

BTW, in Ruby, we write `methods`, not `functions`.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure User.all is defined in its class and make a function using something like this.

User.all.select{|user| user.team=="Hornets" }

[This is A helpful link](https://www.eriktrautman.com/posts/ruby-explained-map-select-and-other-enumerable-methods)

Comment: Yeah I guess I should've  thought of that but since he hasn't figured out how associations work I thought that'd help.